# json - problem with brackets

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

good night

i have a doubt

what reason this output doesn't work `[{"var1":"abc"},{"var2":"abcd"},{"var3":"abcde"}]`

but this works

```
`{"var1":"abc"},{"var2":"abcd"},{"var3":"abcde"}`
```

i already try add this header to the php file `header('Content-type: application/json');` but nothing change, the values are always undefined in the alert output

ajax code

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery("btn").click(function(){
         jQuery.ajax({               
         dataType: 'json', 
            url: "file.php",
            success: function(json){
               send = "first: " + json.var1+ "\n";
               send += "second: " + json.var2";
               alert(send);
            }
         });
      });
   });
```

Comment: try changing your formate{"var1":"abc","var2":"abcd","var3":"abcde"} and check you have echoing via json_encode http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: yes, i use echo json_encode($arr);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first one has the objects in an array, to access them you would need to do...

```
json[0].var1
```

...and so on.

You also have a trailing `"` in your `success` callback.